# HTML5 textarea canvas webGL

Tags: html, canvas, textarea, webgl

i'm looking for a good tutorial on how to make a HTML5 canvas recognize the webgl code I wrote on a textarea in the same page and the canvas render it

help please

i've looked into codemirror but I could't make it work :s

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: the thing is that I don't understand how to have my webgl code in the textarea and make it render in the canvas...
how do I pass that text to my canvas...

Comment: That doesn't really clarify anything, but I still tried to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the GLSL shader program you use, you always follow the same steps:

1. create the pixel- or vertex shaders with `context.createShader`
2. obtain the sourcecodes for the shaders
3. set the sourcecodes for the shaders through `context.shaderSource`
4. compile the shaders with `context.compileShader`
5. create a new webgl program with `context.createProgram`
6. attach the shaders to the program with `context.attachShader`
7. link the shader with `context.linkProgram`
8. tell the canvas to use the complete shader program with `context.useProgram`

Details about these individual steps can be found in any of the countless WebGL tutorials you can google. The only thing you want to do differently is step 2 - how to obtain the sourcecodes of the pixel- and the vertex shader.

Most tutorials store the GLSL sourcecode in `<script>` tags in the DOM. You can do this, but it isn't the only way. You can just as well store it in two textareas of a form and when you submit the form, get the form content and perform the steps above with the content.